# Keyword Planner Tool: How can Exact Match Keywords produce a greater volume of impressions than its Broad Match variant? Bug or misunderstanding?

Tags: seo, keywords, google-ads, google-keyword-tool

Earlier, I wanted to check out how many impressions were being generated for the keyword 'Canvas Prints', for SEO purposes.  Here are my findings:

[image]

**Exact Match > Broad Match and Phrase Match?**

I am a little confused at how the exact match `[canvas prints]` variant, is able to produce more impressions than the broader `canvas prints` variant.

My understanding for Match Types, is as follows:is that broad matches encompasses all references of that keyword.  For example:

**Broad Match Type:**

Broad matches encompass all references of the desired keyword, together with similar keywords and synonyms.  For example:

- Canvas Print Deals;
- Prints on Canvas;
- Canvas Paintings (Maybe).

**Phrase Match Type:**

Phrase matches encompass all search queries, which contain the Keyword as is.  For example:

- Offers on Canvas Prints;
- Large Canvas Prints;
- Black & White Canvas Prints.

**Exact Match Type:**

As the name suggests, this is where the search query contains the exact Keyword only.  As such, producing the sole example of:

- Canvas Prints.

The reason for my confusion being that the Broad Match should be the largest, as it consists of all variants; including the Phrase Match and Exact Match statistics.  The Phrase Match then coming in as the second largest, with the Exact Match having the smallest amount of impressions, as it is targeting a very specific Keyword.

The difference between the Broad Match and Phrase Match, makes sense.  Just not the Exact Match figures.

Have I missed out something here or is there a glitch?

Whilst I am aware that the Google Keyword Planner Tool is primarily for the Google Ads program, I am using this Tool for some simple SEO preliminary research.  I thought I would highlight this, just in case it affects anything; though I cannot see how.